# Double curly braces in angularjs avoid w3c validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, w3c, braces

I have an html page that uses the following line of code:

```
... <a href="nolf://{{server.ip}}:{{server.hostport}}/"> ...
```

When I try to validate the page, I got the following error:

`"Bad value nolf://{{server.ip}}:{{server.hostport}}/ for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in scheme data: not a URL code point."`

It seems that the validator does not like seeing the curly braces in a URL link. If I remove them, all goes well. They are "unsafe" so they need to be encoded but if I encode them, the AngularJS instructions do not work anymore.

Is there a workaround, a way, to validate this? (original page where this code is can be found here: http://oneoakway.com/nolf/servers/ - there is a validation link in the footer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) instead. This will properly apply the expression to a `href` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! "ng-href" still gives an error, "Attribute ng-href not allowed on element a at this point." but then I added the "data-" prefix to it (data-ng-href), as I had to do with all other "ng instructions", and it worked. My page validates now.